# Showing that $x^3+\omega x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb C(\omega)$

Tags: group-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How to show that $f(x)=x^3+\omega x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb C(\omega)$?
This is what I have tried:

Suppose on the contrary that: $$f(x)=g(x)h(x)=(x-\alpha(\omega))(x^2+\beta(\omega)x+\gamma(\omega)).$$ Then $\alpha(\omega)\gamma(\omega)=-1$ and $\gamma(\omega)-\alpha(\omega)\beta(\omega)=\omega$ and $\alpha(\omega)=\beta(\omega)$.

Now, I should conclude that this case is not possible, but I can't see why. Where is contradiction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be an excellent idea if you'd tell us what in the worl is $\,\omega\;$...though I suspect it (root of unity...third...stuff...?)

Comment: $C(\omega)$ is a field of rational expressions over $C$ with one unknown $\omega$ (I'm not sure this is a good translation, sorry for my English).

Comment: Ok, then it is the field of rational *functions* over the complex $\,\Bbb C\,$...we usually denote this by $\,\Bbb C(x)\;$ or $\;\Bbb C(t)\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exist elements $\,a\,,\,b\,,\,c\in\Bbb C(w)\;$ s.t.

$$x^3+wx+1=(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)=x^3+(b-a)x^2+(c-ab)x-ac\implies$$

$$\begin{align*}a&=b\\
ac&=-1\\
c-ab&=c-a^2=w\end{align*}$$

But since the second equality above means $\,a,c\,$ are non-zero polynomials in $\,w\,$ of degree zero (i.e., constants or simply non-zero complex numbers), the last equality tells us that in fact  $\,w\in\Bbb C\,$ , which is absurd.

Comment: good answer! i believe you are implicitly appealing to Gauss's lemma -- irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[\omega]$ iff irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(\omega)$

Comment: Well, yes you're right, though there wasn't even real need of that as the coefficients happened to be zero degree functions adn thus simple numbers.